# UIElement to image file (WP7)

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, uielement

I have a `StackPanel` which includes a few `Rectangles` that I want put to an image file (e.g. PNG). I'm developing this on Windows Phone 7 and most of the information I found on the internet wasn't applicable (I think) to WP7.

I think the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace is the key to this, but I'm not sure where to begin.

**This is basically what I want to do:**

```
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
List<Rectangle> recList = new List<Rectangle>();
```

add some rectangles to `recList`

```
foreach(var x in recList)
     stack.Children.Add(x);
```

then save the stackpanel to an image file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `WriteableBitmap` to save the image.

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(stack, null);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myWidth, myHeight, 0, 100);
```

You can change the `MemoryStream` to be an Isolated Storage stream instead. If you want to display the above `MemoryStream` in an Image control:

```
 BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
 bmp.SetSource(ms);
 image1.Source = bmp;
```

Or, saving to Isolated Storage:

```
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myPicture.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())) 
{                     
    wb.SaveJpeg(isoFileStream, myWidth, myHeight, 0, 100);                    
}
```