# Rendering a usercontrol to an image in the MediaLibrary

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
private void SaveAsPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(MyUIElement, null);
    var library = new MediaLibrary();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, 100, 100, 0, 90);
    library.SavePicture("Certificate", stream);
}
```

This should save the rendering of the MyUIElement to a bmp then save that as a Jpeg in the medialibrary but i'm getting a `value does not fall within expected range` error on the line with `library.SavePicture("Certificate", stream);`

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299978/uielement-to-image-file-wp7/6300024#6300024

Comment: but will it then display in the photo gallery on the phone?

Comment: that question/answer shows how to save to IsolatedStorage and I thought may be relevant. Which line in your code causes the error?

Comment: library.SavePicture("Certificate", stream);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error like the one you had. And I solved it by following the example on [How to: Encode a JPEG for Windows Phone and Save to the Pictures Library on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

So your method should look as following

```
private void SaveAsPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(MyUIElement, null);
    library.SavePicture("Certificate", stream);
    String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

    // Create a virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
    var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }

    IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

    bmp.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    myFileStream.Close();

    // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
    myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // Save the image to the camera roll or saved pictures album.
    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

        // Save the image to the camera roll album.
    library.SavePicture("Certificate", myFileStream);
}
```